# An extra column that explains when a value in the same row was updated

Tags: database, database-design

In my database table, I have a `LastUpdated` column that describes when the current row was last updated.

What the customer has now asked for is to have a few more `DateTime` columns in the table to keep track of individual values within the same row

E.g. there's a column called `Address` and they would like to have an extra column `AddressLastUpdated` to know when it was last changed.

For some reason, this does not look like a good solution. It is certainly doable. But I am wondering if there's a better way of implementing this. Since if we have this in place for one column, chances are they are going to want to have a `LastUpdated` column for every column in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping a bridge table with below structure will help.

Structure :

- Key Column of the table (e.g. Customer Key / Customer No)
- Updated Column Name
- Last Updated Date / DateTime

Above solution will help in 2 ways :

1. Keep the existing table structure intact.
2. All the future such requests can be easily managed.

Comment: Useful approach as it can also keep a history of the changes. Excellent suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to apply it on the DB.